# Objected Expected Error Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following error "Objected Expected" on line 5 of this code in IE8, the code works in Firefox but not IE 8 which is the browser I am developing for. Thanks.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>    
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
if($('#DialogFinalMessage > div').html().length>0){
    window.location.href = "<Desired destination page URL>"
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is line 5 in your code?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Really? Where is the `<doctype>`, the `<html>` etc..? Or is it only in this bit of code line 5?

Comment: Thats just a snippit of the code, I have over 800 lines but the problem lies within this code!

Comment: `$('#DialogFinalMessage > div').html()` will return `null`/`undefined` if it did not find any elements matching the selector. Check if any elements were found before trying to get their source.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery has been loaded successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Problem: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CWHw2/1/)

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var html = $('#DialogFinalMessage > div').html();
    if(html != undefined && html.length > 0){
        window.location.href = ""
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CWHw2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `<script type="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">`